# How to drag & drop file in xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

### when i drag and drop any files than its show like **below image**.

so i want to know that what is "**PrizeperdayTests**"? 
is i have to checked it when adding some files? what if i not cheked it? i ask this question because when i run my app from Xcode it will run but when i try to run my app using api file than its just close instantly.
 [image]

Comment: where you are dragging controls ? means in which file ? is it `.xib` file

Comment: i adding some .h .m .xib and images into my project.

Answer (score 2):

This is a unit test target created by Xcode, probably as part of the project template you chose.

Unless you are dragging in files required by your unit tests, you can leave "PrizeperdayTests" unchecked.

Comment: if i leave it unchecked is it possible that those files are not include while i am creating api file.